# How does this module pattern in Javascript work?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am learning about module patterns, a bit confused about how they behave.

So, I have this simple module,

```
var testModule = (function() {

    //private counter
    var counter = 0;
    return {
        //public methods
        incrementCounter: function () {
            console.log(counter++);
        },
        resetCounter: function () {
            counter = 0;
        }
    };
}());
```

From what I have understood till now(and please correct me if I am wrong), the above function will be invoked immediately(because of the parentheses).

When it runs, it returns an object, which contains only the public methods defined.

So, in the end, after executing the above function our code will look something like this **internally** **(Please, please correct me if I am wrong. this is only my understanding of its behaviour)**

```
testModule_ = {
    incrementCounter: function () {
        return counter++; 
    },
    resetCounter: function () {
        console.log("counter value prior to reset: " + counter);
        counter = 0;
    }
};
```

The thing which I don't understand is, when we access the public methods as 
`testModule.incrementCounter()` or `testModule.resetCounter()`, how do they get the value of the `counter`, as `testModule` now doesn't have `counter`?

I can see it gets the value for the first time, as when that anonymous function was self invoked, it did increment `counter` and reset the values. But what about second time, from where it gets the value of `counter`?

I hope I am clear.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: By magic, err, …closure!

Comment: It's called a closure. The functions have a *permanent* reference to their enclosing variable scope, so as long as at least one of those functions continues to exist, the `counter` variable will exist and be accessible from those functions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!